# sudo apt-get upgrade turned RPI4 off

Tags: apt, upgrade, raspberrypi

I just ran:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

On my RPI4 and it turned off. The green activity light is blinking. Does anyone know what is up?
Also: I saw that it was stuck for quite a while on updating a package named Wolfram

Comment: `sudo apt get-upgrade` is not a valid command to my knowledge - it should be `sudo apt-get upgrade` - so which one did you run?

Comment: Whoops. Thanks for pointing out. I changed it. I ran: ```sudo apt-get upgrade```

Comment: How could it be stuck on a package (and blinking) if it's turned off? That's thoroughly confusing.

Comment: I guess if it was maxing the processor through some failed process that it might eventually shutdown for exceeding the allowed temperature? I guess, power down, wait until it's cool, reboot and report any errors - check dmesg and apt logs.